# How do I hide/unhide div tag while checking content of textbox via database

Tags: javascript, html, database

Hi guys i might need some help regards to javascript. I'm quite new here however i've tried looking out other posts and still unable to solve this issue.

I have a page containing 2 item consist of a userid tag and a javascript content tag.

1) I would like to display only the userid tag and hide the javascript content

[image]

2) Upon receiving an input from the user in the userid (textbox) and upon clicking retrieve, it will check on my database, and if the userid is valid,

a) it will appear  the javascript content would then auto unhide and appear on its own.

[image]

b) if it is invalid it appear invalid.

[image]

Here are the snippets of the code that i wanna hide:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="idtag">

    <form action="verification.php" method="get">
    <span> User-ID: </span>
    <input class="textbox" type="textbox" name="userid"> 
    <input type="submit" name="retrive" value="Retrive">
    </form>

</div>

<!-- This is the part that i want to hide -->
<div id="CAPTCHA">
    <!-- CAPTCHA CODES HERE --><br>
    <form>
     <img id="IMG_LEFT" src="./lion tail.gif" />
     <img id="IMG_RIGHT" src="./lion head.gif" />
     <p>Move the Bar to Move the Images Closer</p>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" steps="2"    
      oninput="moveRight(value);"/>
     <br />Slider Value = <span id="sliderStaus">0</span>
     <br />Random Distance = <span id="randDist">0</span>
     <br />Correct Spot = <span id="spotBoolean">false</span>
  </form>

</div>

 <div id="invalid">
    <h2> User Invalid </h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance. Help is much appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript, you can do like this:

```
/*Set the Captcha hidden initially &*/
document.getElementById('CAPTCHA').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 

/*Adding listener to input for showing/hiding captcha*/
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    if(document.getElementById('userid').value.length >= 1){
       document.getElementById('CAPTCHA').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }else{
       document.getElementById('CAPTCHA').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  });
```

for this piece of code to work, you just need to add the id 'userid' to the HTML input. So the HTML will be:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="idtag">
    <span> User-ID: </span>
    <input class="textbox" type="textbox" id="userid" name="userid"> 
</div>

<!-- This is the part that i want to hide -->
<div id="CAPTCHA">
    <!-- CAPTCHA CODES HERE --><br>
    <form>
     <img id="IMG_LEFT" src="./lion tail.gif" />
     <img id="IMG_RIGHT" src="./lion head.gif" />
     <p>Move the Bar to Move the Images Closer</p>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" steps="2"    
      oninput="moveRight(value);"/>
     <br />Slider Value = <span id="sliderStaus">0</span>
     <br />Random Distance = <span id="randDist">0</span>
     <br />Correct Spot = <span id="spotBoolean">false</span>
  </form>

</div>
</div>
```

Refer this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyq3s7m5/)

Comment: Apologies, @Aswin KK however i yet to finish my question and posted

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want a pure javascript solution, like this:

**HTML**

Same that you have

**CSS**

```
#CAPTCHA {display: none;}
```

**JS**

```
var textbox = document.querySelector('.textbox');
textbox.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if(this.value.length > 0) {
        document.querySelector('#CAPTCHA').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#CAPTCHA').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```js
var textbox = document.querySelector('.textbox');
textbox.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('#CAPTCHA').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#CAPTCHA').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
#CAPTCHA {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="idtag">
    <span> User-ID: </span>
    <input class="textbox" type="textbox" name="userid">
  </div>

  <!-- This is the part that i want to hide -->
  <div id="CAPTCHA">
    <!-- CAPTCHA CODES HERE -->
    <br>
    <form>
      <img id="IMG_LEFT" src="./lion tail.gif" />
      <img id="IMG_RIGHT" src="./lion head.gif" />
      <p>Move the Bar to Move the Images Closer</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" steps="2" oninput="moveRight(value);" />
      <br />Slider Value = <span id="sliderStaus">0</span>
      <br />Random Distance = <span id="randDist">0</span>
      <br />Correct Spot = <span id="spotBoolean">false</span>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```